# Transform $(xu')' + \frac{\lambda}{x}u=0 $ into $v'' +\lambda v=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this problem: 
$$(xu')' + \frac{\lambda}{x}u=0 $$
How can I get to this form:

$$v'' +\lambda v=0$$

I tried using: $$u(x) = v(t) $$ 
$$x=e^t$$ 
But I can't get to anything.
Just give me a hint.

Comment: Product rule on left?

Comment: @SimpleArt Are you asking? or giving me an answer?

Comment: Giving my thoughts to see if they help.

Comment: Well, this is not helping me. I'm too weak with differential equations!

Comment: Is $\lambda$ positive or negative?

Comment: @choco_addicted: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @choco_addicted I believe it is arbitrary constant.

Comment: @SijaanHallak I'm sorry, but I haven't even taken Calculus, so this is slightly beyond my ability.  I'm trying though.

Comment: @choco_addicted As Alex M. answered: it doesnt matter

Comment: Try product rule, then multiply everything by $x$.  Then substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that $(x u')' = u' + x u''$, your equation gets rewritten as $x^2 u'' + x u' + \lambda u = 0$.

Next, performing the substitution $x = \textrm e ^t$ gives $t = \ln x$, so if $u(x) = v(t) = v(\ln x)$ then $u'(x) = v'(\ln x) \frac 1 x = v'(t) \frac 1 x$ and $u''(x) = v''(\ln x) \frac 1 {x^2} - v'(\ln x) \frac 1 {x^2} = v''(t) \frac 1 {x^2} - v'(t) \frac 1 {x^2}$.

Substituting these formulae for $u''$ and $u'$ into the rewritten equation leads to $v'' + \lambda v = 0$.

Comment: Woo, you beat me to it!  LoL, just in the process of sorting stuff out.

Comment: @SimpleArt I really appreciate your help bud.

Comment: @SijaanHallak Anytime.  Teamwork!  (I feel great though, that would've been the first differential equation I would've sort of solved)

Comment: Sounds like a Sturm-Liouville differential equation... but is one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Does it matter for the given question?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. But if you want to enlarge a little the scope of this question for being able to solve neighbour problems, it could be of interest, in order to be beyond a witty transformation. The $\lambda$ for example is not there by chance...

Comment: @JeanMarie: I beg to disagree: I have seen numerous problems of this type, the only purpose of which being to teach the student how to reduce Euler-Cauchy equations to 2nd order ODEs with constant coefficients.